# Is jQuery interpreting it wrong? or Drupal outputting wrong?

Tags: jquery, drupal

I'm facing a peculiar problem. My Drupal website uses Jquery 1.4.4 version.

As you all know, Drupal outputs `Drupal.settings` json to Javascript as:

**when I enable `devel_themer` module**:

The following is the output

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {
   "basePath":"\/d7\/",
   "pathPrefix":"",
   "ajaxPageState":{
      "theme":"bartik",
      "theme_token":"KC2-1Z9CN5PCxDyAq_W8FGBQBOOnwt8AyoeX1UDBoP8",
      "js":{
         "misc\/jquery.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.once.js":1,
         "misc\/drupal.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.min.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.widget.min.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.cookie.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.form.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.resizable.min.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.ba-bbq.js":1,
         "modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.js":1,
         "misc\/ajax.js":1,
         "misc\/progress.js":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel_themer\/devel_themer.js":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel\/krumo\/krumo.js":1,
         "modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.js":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel\/devel_krumo_path.js":1
      },
      "css":{
         "modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.theme.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.resizable.css":1,
         "modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.css":1,
         "modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,
         "modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,
         "modules\/node\/node.css":1,
         "modules\/search\/search.css":1,
         "modules\/user\/user.css":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel_themer\/devel_themer.css":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel\/krumo\/skins\/default\/skin.css":1,
         "modules\/shortcut\/shortcut.css":1,
         "modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.css":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel_themer\/devel_themer_ie_fix.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/layout.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/style.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/colors.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/print.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/ie.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/ie6.css":1
      }
   },
   "thmrStrings":{
      "themer_info":"Themer info",
      "toggle_throbber":" \u003Cimg src=\u0022\/d7\/sites\/all\/modules\/devel_themer\/loader-little.gif\u0022 alt=\u0022loading\u0022 class=\u0022throbber\u0022 width=\u002216\u0022 height=\u002216\u0022 style=\u0022display:none\u0022 \/\u003E",
      "parents":"Parents: ",
      "function_called":"Function called: ",
      "template_called":"Template called: ",
      "candidate_files":"Candidate template files: ",
      "preprocessors":"Preprocess functions: ",
      "processors":"Process functions: ",
      "candidate_functions":"Candidate function names: ",
      "drupal_api_docs":"link to Drupal API documentation",
      "source_link_title":"link to source code",
      "function_arguments":"Function Arguments",
      "template_variables":"Template Variables",
      "file_used":"File used: ",
      "duration":"Duration: ",
      "api_site":"http:\/\/api.drupal.org\/",
      "drupal_version":"7",
      "source_link":"\/d7\/devel\/source?file="
   },
   "thmr_popup":"  \u003Cdiv id=\u0022themer-fixeder\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv id=\u0022themer-relativer\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv id=\u0022themer-popup\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022topper\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cspan class=\u0022close\u0022\u003EX\u003C\/span\u003E Drupal Themer Information\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv id=\u0022parents\u0022 class=\u0022row\u0022\u003E\n\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022info row\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022starter\u0022\u003EClick on any element to see information about the Drupal theme function or template that created it.\u003C\/div\u003E\n        \u003Cdl\u003E\n          \u003Cdt class=\u0022key-type\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dt\u003E\n          \u003Cdd class=\u0022key\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dd\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv class=\u0022used\u0022\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n          \u003Cdt class=\u0022candidates-type\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dt\u003E\n          \u003Cdd class=\u0022candidates\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dd\u003E\n\n          \u003Cdt class=\u0022preprocessors-type\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dt\u003E\n          \u003Cdd class=\u0022preprocessors\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dd\u003E\n          \u003Cdt class=\u0022processors-type\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dt\u003E\n          \u003Cdd class=\u0022processors\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dd\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv class=\u0022duration\u0022\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n        \u003C\/dl\u003E\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\u003C!-- \/info --\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022attributes row\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022themer-variables\u0022\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\u003C!-- \/attributes --\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\u003C!-- \/themer-popup --\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E",
   "overlay":{
      "paths":{
         "admin":"node\/*\/edit\nnode\/*\/delete\nnode\/*\/revisions\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/revert\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/delete\nnode\/add\nnode\/add\/*\noverlay\/dismiss-message\nuser\/*\/shortcuts\nadmin\nadmin\/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/cancel\nuser\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/edit\/*\ndevel\/*\nnode\/*\/devel\nnode\/*\/devel\/*\ncomment\/*\/devel\ncomment\/*\/devel\/*\nuser\/*\/devel\nuser\/*\/devel\/*\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\/*",
         "non_admin":"admin\/structure\/block\/demo\/*\nadmin\/reports\/status\/php"
      },
      "pathPrefixes":[

      ],
      "ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"
   },
   "tableHeaderOffset":"Drupal.toolbar.height"
});
```

and in the browser console, as you can see in the following screenshot `Drupal.settings` object has some strange objects. 
[image]

**What is strange about this?**

If I write `Drupal.settings.thmrStrings` in console, it says undefinied. But According to above objects, there should be. Instead of showing these meaningful objects, according to json it shows generated some strange objects like `Drupal.settings.thmr_1`, `Drupal.settings.thmr_2`, `Drupal.settings.thmr_3` .. `Drupal.settings.thmr_94`. Where are these `Drupal.settings.thmr_*` objects coming from? They are not in the json? Why are the objects not according to jSON?

The error that you see in the screenshot is caused because of this. The javascript file `devel_themer.js` is accessing a sub-object of `Drupal.settings.thmrStrings` but its not getting it. Thats is the main problem why I got behind this.

**when I disable `devel_themer` module**:

The following is the output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {
   "basePath":"\/d7\/",
   "pathPrefix":"",
   "ajaxPageState":{
      "theme":"bartik",
      "theme_token":"KC2-1Z9CN5PCxDyAq_W8FGBQBOOnwt8AyoeX1UDBoP8",
      "js":{
         "misc\/jquery.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.once.js":1,
         "misc\/drupal.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.min.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.ba-bbq.js":1,
         "modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.js":1,
         "modules\/contextual\/contextual.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.cookie.js":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel\/devel_krumo_path.js":1,
         "modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.js":1
      },
      "css":{
         "modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.theme.css":1,
         "modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.css":1,
         "modules\/contextual\/contextual.css":1,
         "modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,
         "modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,
         "modules\/node\/node.css":1,
         "modules\/search\/search.css":1,
         "modules\/user\/user.css":1,
         "modules\/shortcut\/shortcut.css":1,
         "modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/layout.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/style.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/colors.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/print.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/ie.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/ie6.css":1
      }
   },
   "overlay":{
      "paths":{
         "admin":"node\/*\/edit\nnode\/*\/delete\nnode\/*\/revisions\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/revert\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/delete\nnode\/add\nnode\/add\/*\noverlay\/dismiss-message\nuser\/*\/shortcuts\nadmin\nadmin\/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/cancel\nuser\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/edit\/*\ndevel\/*\nnode\/*\/devel\nnode\/*\/devel\/*\ncomment\/*\/devel\ncomment\/*\/devel\/*\nuser\/*\/devel\nuser\/*\/devel\/*\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\/*",
         "non_admin":"admin\/structure\/block\/demo\/*\nadmin\/reports\/status\/php"
      },
      "pathPrefixes":[

      ],
      "ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"
   },
   "tableHeaderOffset":"Drupal.toolbar.height"
});
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

and in the browser console as you can see the following picture `Drupal.settings` object is interpreted properly. I mean, objects are as per json. There are no strange objects like in the above case.

[image]

**Question:** What is causing this strange behaviour? How to rectify it?

Comment: might be due to ajax. check this out - https://drupal.org/node/1683154

Comment: well, then the JSON must have been changed during runtime. you could try to set a [watch](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#favorite-expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal devel_themer module manipulates the Drupal.settings JSON response after receiving it from the server.  The [source code](http://tinyurl.com/k6fdww6) shows that as soon as the page is loaded that devel_themer modifies the Drupal.settings value:

```
if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      lastObj = false;
      thmrSpanified = false;
      strs = Drupal.settings.thmrStrings;
      $('body').addClass("thmr_call").attr("id", "thmr_" + Drupal.settings.page_id);
      ...
```

You should be able to access the unaltered original Drupal.settings by defining another $(document).ready function prior to the devel_themer one.  document.ready() callbacks are called in the order they were registered so you will need to do this earlier in your code.  You already have a dependency of jQuery so use it to deep clone the object...

```
if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    Drupal.originalSettings = jQuery.extend(true, {}, Drupal.settings);    
    // alert(Drupal.originalSettings.thmrStrings.themer_info);
    // ... do your thing ...
  });
}
```

You will need to insert this $(document).ready function after the Drupal.settings have been loaded and before the dev_themer module initializes.